Why does my angular 18 material design tokens not override theme?
I'm currently trying out the design tokens on Angular 18.2.10. I've ran into in an issue with my project when applying the design tokens override for a slide toggle. It seems that some style overrides the angular material azure theme while others are not.
Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-i9rg73?file=angular.json
My folder structure:
I've a styles.scss with @forward './assets/styles/main.scss'; only in it. In my assets folder I have two style sheets a main.scss and _variables.scss. Main's content is: @forward './_variables';. In _variables.scss is where the magic is happening.
_variables.scss:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$white-0: #ffffff;
$grey-600: #72777e;
$grey-800: #3c4046;
$grey-1000: #15181b;

:root {
  @include mat.slide-toggle-overrides((
   unselected-track-color: $grey-800,
   unselected-icon-color: $grey-1000,
   unselected-pressed-track-color: $grey-800,
   unselected-hover-track-color: $grey-800,
   unselected-focus-track-color: $grey-800,
   unselected-handle-color: $grey-600,
   selected-icon-color: $grey-1000,
   selected-handle-color: $white-0,
   selected-focus-handle-color: $white-0,
   selected-track-color: $grey-800,
  ));
 }

This is what I see in the console: 


How do I make sure that my styling overrides the azure-blue theme?

your example works fine for me. some overrides just do not work. guess that's a bug.

@RobinDijkhof those overrides are supposed to work otherwise the code wouldn't compile. They come from the angular material documentation

That's why I think it is a bug. Maybe create a github issue

The selector for applying the CSS variables has a lower specificity than the ones that apply the Material ones. So in general your setup works correctly, however some of your variables are overridden by Angular Material again. You can also see this in the DevTools, the properties are striked through:

To fix it, choose a selector with sufficient specificity:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

:root mat-slide-toggle.mat-mdc-slide-toggle {
  @include mat.slide-toggle-overrides(
    (
      // your overrides
    )
  );
}

Also see the updated StackBlitz.

Alright it seems like it works. Is there some documentation about this? I would think that  the mixin from angular/material would've been enough

@userp it's not well documented, when checking the docs it seems like your code is fine. Maybe you can create an issue on their GitHub.
